# Why does Ira Glass adds "of course" when explaining the nature of the show This American Life?

Tags: phrase-usage

I've listened to dozens of episodes of the This American Life podcast so far and I wonder why its host almost always adds "of course" when he describes the show at the beginning of each episode.
Here's an example -

> Each week on our program, **of course**, we choose some theme and bring
>   you documentaries, monologues, overheard conversations, found tape,
>   found text, anything we can think of on that theme.

Comment: In English we often use *of course* to acknowledge that we are delivering routine information that would appear to be self-evident or otherwise well-known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Robusto says, it's to acknowledge that we're delivering routine information.

This can be explained by the [Cooperative Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle#Maxim_of_quantity). In [pragmatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics), we're theorized to tacitly obey a few "maxims" to make our conversation effective and efficient. Here, we're concerned with the **maxim of quantity**:

> 1. Make your contribution as informative as is required (for the current purposes of the exchange).
> 2. **Do not make your contribution more informative than is required.**

No doubt you've often met people who tell you something you didn't need to hear, because you already know it or it's obvious. For example, you might be tightening a screw and someone could say, "Remember, right is tighter, left is looser," even as you're doing it correctly. Or they could tell you a story about their childhood that, interesting though it may be, you've heard a dozen times. It can be annoying.

In the podcast, I guess the repeated introduction is part of the format, whether for the benefit of new listeners or just [because it's enjoyable to hear the same thing each time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdjL8WXjlGI). But a lot of media today addresses the listener or reader or watcher more personally than before, so it becomes more like a conversation. I find this true of podcasts and YouTube, anyway. And if it's a conversation with a regular audience that has heard all this before, the podcaster is violating the maxim of quantity by telling us something we know.

**This is where *of course* comes in.** The maxims of the Cooperative Principle can be [hedged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_(linguistics)) — you can acknowledge or apologize for not following a maxim. "Of course" is such a hedge.

We could paraphrase it:

> I know this is obvious by now...
>
> You might know this already, but just for those who don't...
>
> We have to say this each week, so bear with me for 20 seconds...

In everyday life, this sometimes happens when we start to say something and then realize that the other person knows it. Then we might say "of course" and hurry through the rest of the sentence.

Comment: The repeated introduction is because _This American Life_ is a radio show and doesn't expect all listeners to have started at the beginning.

Comment: @Deolater I meant repeated once per episode — I don't know the show myself but was going by the OP's question. Not everyone might hear the introduction each time, but for those who do, there's "of course". :)

Comment: Your answer is great. I was just explaining why this particular show is so repetitive. Glass probably introduces show every five minutes.